# What does a period mean in a variable name?

Tags: java

I saw this in my textbook and was wondering what it was and when to know to use it.

```
public class TV{
    public static final int MAX.VOLUME = 10; 
    public static final int DEFAULT.CHANNEL = 2;
    public static final int DEFAULT.VOLUME = 4;
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's a period `.` and not an underscore  `_`? As far as I can tell, that would result in a syntax error.

Comment: You're right! The page was badly copied and I couldn't read it. I was wondering why it gave me an error when I tried to compile it. Thank you!

Comment: And to address why the underscore is there, it's standard convention to represent normal variables usingCamelCaseWithoutWordSeparators, and constants USING_UPPER_CASE_AND_UNDERSCORES.

Answer (score 2):

In java, there are certain rules when defining a variable name.

> A variable name must **not**,

- be a java keyword
- contain spaces

> The first character of a variable name,

- **can** be a character (`a-z|A-Z`)
- **can** be a dollar sign (`$`)
- **can** be a underscore (`_`)
- **can not** be a number (`0-9`)

> The rest of the name **can** contain any combination from the following,

- characters (`a-z|A-Z`)
- dollar signs (`$`)
- underscores (`_`)
- numbers (`0-9`)

> All variable names are **case-sensitive**.

---

So using a period (`.`) in the middle of an variable name will result in a compile error.